How do i remove Hidden Header H2 from website in wordpress?
I am facing a problem that my website pages have H1 as a title of page and then same title is duplicated as H2 in website but i cannot see it. I am unable to to find that Hidden H2 so i can remove that H2
I try to find code of that H2 to remove but unable to find it. and it exist in Google

It depends on your theme. But you can use JS to remove any element, I'm not sure this is what you want.
